# Why is the point at infinity of the affine equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1 - (xy)^2$ singular?

Tags: elliptic-curves, singularity

The equation of the plane projective curve is $f(x,y,z) = (xz)^2 + (yz)^2 - z^4 + (xy)^2$. Two points at infinity are $(1:0:0)$ and $(0:1:0)$. The definition says that a point $P$ is singular if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ all vanish at $P$. But $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x(y^2 + z^2)$, which I think exists at $(1:0:0)$, so where did I start going wrong?

Comment: Dehomogenizing wrt $x$: $(z)^2 + (yz)^2 - z^4 + (y)^2=0$ has tangent cone $y^2+z^2=0$ which is a line pair over ${\Bbb C}$, and dehomogenizing wrt $y$: $(xz)^2 + (z)^2 - z^4 + (x)^2=0$ has tangent cone $x^2+z^2=0$ which is a line pair over ${\Bbb C}$.

Comment: “Exists” and “vanishes” aren’t antonyms. Indeed, for the derivative to vanish at a point it must exist there in the first place. $f_x$ of course _exists_ at $1:0:0$, but what is its value there?